# How to know if a PostfixExpression belongs to a for statement?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-jdt

I'm using eclipse parser to work with expressions and statements in java code.

I have a function:

```
    public boolean visit(PostfixExpression node)
```

which deals with `Postfix` expressoins, such ass `i++`;

Problem is i want to distinguish between a `for statement` postfix, and other postfixes.
I thought maybe i could get to the `node`'s `parent` and somehow check if it's a `for`. Something like `node.getParent()`... but `node.getParent()` doesn't return an `expression`.

Any ideas how to recognize if the `PostfixExpression` belongs to a `for loop`?

Thanks

**edit:**

By "`for statement` postfix" i mean the postfix in the `for loop`'s first line. Such as:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
```

So i want to distinguish this `i++` from other `i++`'s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a for_updaters List (using `node.updaters()`) and updating it every time i visit a `for` loop (could also be `nested loops`). Also, whenever i come across a `PostfixExpression` (including `for updaters`), i add it to another List, and then delete from this List all similar occurrences that appear in for_updaters List. This way i'm only left with non-for-updaters Postfixes. This also works for me because every time i visit a `for` loop i clear both Lists, so no worries about duplicate variable names.

*Note:* `node.updaters()` returns the exact full expression: `[i++]`. But i only need `i`. It's easy to extract it by converting the `updater` to `String` and then use `substring()`.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just call `ASTNode.getParent()` to see what kind of statement the expression is contained in?